# Mpirun: How to print STDOUT of just one process?

Tags: mpi, openmpi

When running

```
mpirun -n 2 <prg>
```

the STDOUT streams of both processes are combined and are displayed by the shell. In such an interleaved format its hard to tell what line comes from which node.

Is there a way to have mpirun just merger STDOUT of one process to its STDOUT stream?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possbile. I'm not sure what language you are using but you could define a preprocessor macro which overloads your print statements, either so that the process rank is also written or so that your print statements are wrapped in an if statement which checks the process rank.

Answer (score 1):

The solution provides the following wrapper:

```
#!/bin/sh
ARGS=$@
if [[ $OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK == 0 ]]
then
  $ARGS
else
  $ARGS 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
fi
```

Thanks to Paul Kapinos!

http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2012/02/18362.php

Comment: Try to avoid link-only answers. If the site goes down or gets restructured your answers would no longer be valid. How about summarising the solution from the linked page?

Comment: I will summarise the solution. The link was meant to be a placeholder for it.